# Parallel lookup in L1 / L2 / LLC / DRAM?

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, mmu

It's a weird question, but maybe someone here knows:
Referring to Intel/AMD up-to-date processors,
does the CPU lookup the caches and DRAM simultaneously?

It might be a good way to save cycles (but is probably more power consuming).

Any answer (preferably with references) will be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: Except many processors are now multi-core and even on single core you may have DMA transfers. These will cause bus contention which might actually slow things down.

Comment: Not only is parallel memory and cache access avoided, but non-L1 caches typically check tags before accessing any data. In a multi-CPU system, memory is often accessed before coherence responses have returned (so there is a chance that the memory bandwidth would be wasted, if the cache block was present and dirty in another CPU's cache—present but clean would use memory bandwidth but save some bandwidth in the inter-CPU connection). Peak (much less typical) memory bandwidth is *much* lower than L1 bandwidth **and** use cache block granularity.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is NO. The processor usually looks up L1 first. In case of an L1 miss, it looks up L2 then. If it misses, it looks up DRAM.

The whole point of the cache hierarchy is to have faster data access by storing most frequently accessed data in cache. DRAM is pretty slow compared to cache. As the cache level increases (for example, going from L1 to L2), the access latency and capacity increases.

Why not send a parallel lookup to all levels? It is because of energy and bandwidth conversation. Looking up all caches and DRAM (if possible) incurs a lot of energy overhead. Also, as you traverse the memory hierarchy up (for example, going from last level cache to DRAM), the bandwidth goes down. So, in practice, DRAM does not provide enough bandwidth to keep up with processor requests if caches do not filter most requests. In brief, parallel lookup is not feasible. If you are really interested, you may take a look at this recent [paper](http://www.it.uu.se/katalog/andse541/isca14-final.pdf) that proposes a method to locate data in the cache hierarchy instead of traversing the cache hierarchy (which is the common way). The main goal of this proposal is to save energy by eliminating unnecessary cache lookups.

Note 1: I am ignoring coherence here.

Note 2: There could be an L3, or even L4. Also, some I/O devices might be directly connected to DRAM using DMA engines.

Comment: thanks @aminfar. Do you have any references supporting your claim? or it's a secret the hardware vendors keep for themselves?

Comment: It's not a secret at all. You can find this info on major computer architecture books. If I find a reference, I will post it here.

Comment: You're right about the lookup being faster the closer the cache is, but I understood the question as "why not send a parallel lookup to all levels, to shave some cycles off the longer ones". In that case the answer would probably need to account for power and bandwidth conservation.

Comment: @Leeor I addressed your comment.